# error 403 showing while fetching the flight data from API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

There are the errors

[image: 1]

Theses are the errors.

```
componentDidMount() {
        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://timetable-lookup.p.rapidapi.com/TimeTable/BOS/LAX/20191217/',
            headers: {
              'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'SIGN-UP-FOR-KEY',
              'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'timetable-lookup.p.rapidapi.com'
            }
          };

          axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
```

i am trying to fetch data for a flight booking system and getting this error.

Comment: *The HTTP 403 Forbidden response status code indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it.* Perhaps your API key is not valid - did you *'SIGN-UP-FOR-KEY'* or did you think that WAS the key?

Comment: Are you sure your `X-RapidAPI-Key` is correct? I think you copied from the documentation. You have to replace `X-RapidAPI-Key` with the value of the API key